# How to set common prefix for all tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know there is a way to instrument SQLAlchemy to prepend common `prefix` to all **columns**, is it possible to add a common `prefix` to all **table names** derived from single `declarative_base`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`declared_attr`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr) and a customized `Base` along the lines of:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class PrefixerBase(Base):

    __abstract__ = True

    _the_prefix = 'someprefix_'

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls._the_prefix + cls.__incomplete_tablename__


class SomeModel(PrefixerBase):

    __incomplete_tablename__ = 'sometable'
    ...
```

A class marked with [`__abstract__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract) will not get a table or mapper created and can act as the extended declarative base.

You could also make it even more implicit using a custom metaclass ([originally described here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/1JwomyA4Hwk)):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import DeclarativeMeta


class PrefixerMeta(DeclarativeMeta):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        if '__tablename__' in dict_:
            cls.__tablename__ = dict_['__tablename__'] = \
                'someprefix_' + dict_['__tablename__']

        return super().__init__(name, bases, dict_)

Base = declarative_base(metaclass=PrefixerMeta)


class SomeModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'sometable'
    ...
```

Comment: I've tried the ``@declared_attr`` approach, but it breaks when Single-Table-Inheritance is used, I'll try the metaclass through

Comment: Also, unfortunately as far as I understand this won't work with ``M2M`` join tables, witch if not explicit don't inherit fro declarative base

Comment: No, it would not work for manual `Table`s, as they have nothing to do with declarative. For those consider using a wrapper function or such.

Comment: I'll just make them as a subclass of `declarative`` easy enough, thanks for that

Comment: Btw how does `@declared_attr` break with single table inheritance? Asking out of sheer interest.

Comment: It converts it to Joined Table Inheritance, by declaring ``__tablename__`` attribute on a subclass (You can use ``@declared_attr.cascading`` and somehow detect that STI, but I don't know how :) )